# Angular doesn't show an error if a nonexistent event name is used

Tags: angular

Since Angular's [Ivy](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/STATUS.md) renderer is released [strictTemplates](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) compiler option became available. Now there're a lot more compile-time checks in templates and it's great. But one thing I've faced is that there is no warnings/errors if I use a nonexistent event name in a template, for example:

```html
<div (nonexistentEvent)="doSomething()"></div>
```

gives no errors if `nonexistentEvent` doesn't exist. If an event was renamed, it's very easy to miss some of it usages and get bugs as a result. Is there a way to force Angular to complain about such nonexistent event?

Comment: Have you tried compiling in release mode to see if that catches it? `ng build --prod=true`

Comment: @Igor Unfortunately no, it compiles without errors

Comment: It looks more like an issue report than a question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [This is still an active issue even after 5 years](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3426).

> it's very easy to miss some of it usages and get bugs as a result.

You could write a test which could check if component's html template contains event string

Nah, forget about it.